# toggle comment in sublime text 2 does not work for .cs files

Tags: c#, sublimetext2

I have the problem that I cannot toggle block comments in sublime text 2 in any .cs files.
It works perfectly with any other source file type (c,cpp...). It does not work when I select the command via the Edit->Comment->Toggle comment as well when I am using the shortcut.

I have a bunch of plugins installed but I disabled all c# related once with no effect.

Is there a way where I can check if there is somewhere a conflict with this command or where I can find some error log? (the console does not display any error)

kind regards.

goTAN

Comment: To check what's happening, you can open the console (<kbd>⌃`</kbd>), do `sublime.log_commands(True), and then hit the keybinding to see if the `command: toggle_comment {"block": false}` is triggered or not.

Comment: yes it is triggered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a "Comments.tmPreferences" file under your "Packages/C#" folder.
And it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Comments</string>
   <key>scope</key>
   <string>source.cs</string>
   <key>settings</key>
   <dict>
      <key>shellVariables</key>
      <array>
         <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
            <key>value</key>
            <string>// </string>
         </dict>
      </array>
   </dict>
   <key>uuid</key>
   <string>1BA75B32-707C-11D9-A928-000D93589AF6</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Sublime text 3 doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. Can you still explain what the issue is/was? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: It's a key file to tell Sublime Text how to comment code for this specific language("//" for C, "#" for python). For some reason, ST2 missed that file in C# package, so we have to create on our own. ST3 has it natively, so ST3 doesn't have this issue :)